# ExtJS 5: disable form fields in hidden card

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have  a form panel with a radiogroup, and depending on the radiogroup selection, it will show some other components.  If a radiofield is not selected, then its items will be hidden, as they're not part of the active card.

Now, if I have `allowblank: false` set on a field (and it's empty) within the hidden card, my form is still considered invalid.  Being hidden means the user would not like to use it, so it should not be considered as part of the form.  Here's an [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10lq).

In the example, I have 2 forms... the top form is the one that I'm curious about... is there a way to get this working without having to bind to disabled?  I tried looking at [`hideMode`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-hideMode), but that wasn't what I was looking for.

Ideally, I wouldn't have to create a formula for each card that I add... that seems silly.  I realize I could create a generic formula, but once again, that just seems extraneous.  Another option could be ditching the card layout, and binding each card to hidden and disabled, but I'm creating more formulas.  Is there some sort of property I'm missing?

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.define('MyController', {
      extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
      alias: 'controller.myview',
      onValidityChange: function(form, isValid, eOpts) {
        this.getViewModel().set('isFormValid', isValid);
      }
    });
    Ext.define('MyViewModel', {
      extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
      alias: 'viewmodel.myview',
      data: {
        activeItem: {
          myInput: 0
        }
      },
      formulas: {
        activeCardLayout: function(getter) {
          var myInput = getter('activeItem.myInput');
          console.log(myInput);
          return parseInt(myInput);
        }
      }
    });
    Ext.define('MyForm', {
      extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
      title: 'My Form',
      controller: 'myview',
      viewModel: {
        type: 'myview'
      },
      layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
      },
      listeners: {
        validitychange: 'onValidityChange'
      },
      dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        layout: {
          type: 'hbox'
        },
        items: [{
          xtype: 'button',
          text: 'Save',
          reference: 'saveButton',
          disabled: true,
          bind: {
            disabled: '{!isFormValid}'
          }
        }]
      }],
      items: [{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        vertical: true,
        columns: 1,
        bind: {
          value: '{activeItem}'
        },
        defaults: {
          name: 'myInput'
        },
        items: [{
          boxLabel: 'None',
          inputValue: '0'
        }, {
          boxLabel: 'Something',
          inputValue: '1'
        }]
      }, {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'card',
        flex: 1,
        bind: {
          activeItem: '{activeCardLayout}'
        },
        items: [{
          xtype: 'container',
          layout: 'fit'
        }, {
          xtype: 'container',
          layout: 'fit',
          items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'hello',
            allowBlank: false
          }]
        }]
      }]
    });
    Ext.define('MyViewModel2', {
      extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
      alias: 'viewmodel.myview2',
      data: {
        activeItem: {
          myInput: 0
        }
      },
      formulas: {
        disableSomethingCard: function(getter) {
          return getter('activeItem.myInput') !== '1';
        },
        activeCardLayout: function(getter) {
          var myInput = getter('activeItem.myInput');
          console.log(myInput, 'here');
          return parseInt(myInput);
        }
      }
    });
    Ext.define('MyForm2', {
      extend: 'MyForm',
      title: 'My Form 2 (works)',
      viewModel: {
        type: 'myview2'
      },
      items: [{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        vertical: true,
        columns: 1,
        bind: {
          value: '{activeItem}'
        },
        defaults: {
          name: 'myInput'
        },
        items: [{
          boxLabel: 'None',
          inputValue: '0'
        }, {
          boxLabel: 'Something',
          inputValue: '1'
        }]
      }, {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'card',
        flex: 1,
        bind: {
          activeItem: '{activeCardLayout}'
        },
        items: [{
          xtype: 'container',
          layout: 'fit'
        }, {
          xtype: 'container',
          layout: 'fit',
          bind: {
            disabled: '{disableSomethingCard}'
          },
          items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'hello',
            allowBlank: false
          }]
        }]
      }]
    });
    Ext.create('MyForm', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
    Ext.create('MyForm2', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
  }
});
```